# pandas dataframe list columns having some value for each row

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataset of 400+ columns where the first column is a company identifier, the second is an article identifier and the others some attributes of the article. There are > 50.000 companies and up to 1.000 articles per company. For most companies, the attribute values (of importance for me) of all articles are identical, but not for all.
I am using python dataframes to analyse the data.
I'd like to add a column where all differing columns for each company are listed.

Example (using ints for article and company for easier reading):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'company':[1,1,2,2,3,3], 'article':[1,2,1,2,1,2], 'col1':[1,1,2,2,3,3], 'col2':[1,2,3,3,4,4], 'col3':[1,2,3,3,4,5] })
diff = df.groupby('company').nunique()
diff['diff_columns'] = ???
diff[['company', 'diff_columns']]
```

The result should look like this:

```
company   diff_columns
1         ['col2', 'col3']
2         []
3         ['col3']
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the value in each column. Then use [itertools.compress()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) to filter list by the boolean list.

```py
import itertools

columns_to_diff = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']

diff = df.groupby('company').apply(lambda group: list(itertools.compress(columns_to_diff, [(len(group[col].value_counts()) != 1) for col in columns_to_diff])))
```

```
print(diff.to_frame('diff_columns'))

         diff_columns
company              
1        [col2, col3]
2                  []
3              [col3]
```

Comment: unfortunately, this does not work for arbitrary numbers of articles per company. Edited question to clarify size of data

Comment: The trick with len(...value_count()) does it, thank you.